# How to use a query's results as column names in a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

My ultimate goal is to create a pivot-table view in MySQL with dynamic columns based on the contents of another table. At the moment I am trying to continue on from where [artfulsoftware](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78) leaves off; right now I can query for results that give me my desired column names. Unfortunately I'm lost on how to actually use the results as column names in a SELECT statement. I suspect that MySQL variables will be helpful, but I can't figure it out.

To clarify the problem, say I have a table like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| countpivotarg                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ,SUM(IF(domain = "test.com",1,0)) AS `test.com`   |
| ,SUM(IF(domain = "test2.com",1,0)) AS `test2.com` |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to create a select statement that looks like:

```
SELECT id,
       meta_id,
       SUM(IF(domain = "test.com",1,0)) AS `test.com`,
       SUM(IF(domain = "test2.com",1,0)) AS `test2.com`
FROM   myTable;
```

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [MySQL Server prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for building dynamic queries from string variables.

Example:

```
SELECT domain INTO @colname FROM myTable LIMIT 1;
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT `',@colname,'` FROM myTable');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Note: backticks are required in case column names contain spaces.

Comment: How do I get the results into a variable to use in a prepared statement?

Comment: @JoBu1324 Declare a variable, and use `SELECT x INTO x` given your variable name.

Comment: AFAIK, `SELECT @variable_1:=field_1, @variable_2:=field_2, ... FROM ...`. Please check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html. `SELECT x into @x` will also do the trick, thanks, @George!

Comment: Using your suggestion I'm getting "Result consisted of more than one row - can a variable only contain one row?

Comment: This doesn't work: SELECT...INTO only works with one row: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: Yes, variable may contain only one row and field. This limitation can be worked around by using loop statements (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop-statement.html) and LIMIT clauses. This is not an easy way, but this can be done.

Also please note that dynamic SQL by many is considered to be a bad practice. At least, it will definitely have worse performance than 'usual' static SQL.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL, the column names must be fixed at query prepare time -- no exceptions.  Designing a dynamic pivot query when you don't know the columns requires that you write application code either way.  You have a choice between using a preprocessing approach or a postprocessing approach:

- **Preprocessing:** Write a query to fetch a list of the distinct values.  Then use these as column names, and generate a new dynamic SQL query.
- **Postprocessing:** Write a query to fetch the data as a non-pivoted result, and then fetch all the data and pivot into another format.

Comment: I think Sergey is on the right track - I don't see any reason I can't store the results of a query in a variable and use the variable in a new statement. From the perspective of the statement those column names would be known beforehand.

Comment: @JoBu1324: Bill is totally right with his answer - what I was describing is exactly Preprocessing approach.

Comment: I took "requires that you write application code" to mean it couldn't be done in SQL - hence my reply, since I'm doing it entirely in SQL.