# Is there any way in MySQL, to create a single select statement where the select column is the result of another query?

Tags: mysql

My first select statement would be like below,

```
SELECT m.col_name
     , m.col_alias
  FROM <table_name> m 
 WHERE m.exportable LIKE '%Y%'
```

And I'm trying to create a second select query with the data that I'm receiving from the first statement, like below

```
SELECT tabella.id alias_1
     , tabella.value alias_2
     , **“list of col_name result of the previous query”
  FROM <another_table> tabella
 WHERE tabella.metadata_id = 'CI_INDEX||CI_01'*
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use JOIN, is it possible in your case?

Comment: This is a basic question about JOINs. IIt certainly does not merit an upvote.

Comment: What are the common column on both queries? Its a basic join.

Comment: My apology, I suppose, this is not a simple join, if it is, then I guess, I can do that. I'm trying to generate dynamic select statement on the basis of first query.

Comment: I guess I got my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362515/how-to-use-a-querys-results-as-column-names-in-a-select-statement). Anyway thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Try  the [Subquery](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/).
You will find an example in the links.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have relation between them then go for Join

if the tables do not have relation you can use the following format.

```
select table1.col1,table2.col1 from table1, table2
where table1.colx like '%exp%' and table2.coly like '%exp2%'
```